# Meson wave function

Tags: wavefunction, bosons, mesons

I have a basic question about pseudoscalar mesons wavefunction.

As I understand it, mesons are bosons so they have a total symmetric wavefunction under exchange of particles.

For pseudoscalar mesons, the spacial wavefunction is anti-symmetric because the parity is negative ($P=(-1)^{L+1}$ and $L=0$ ).

The spin wavefunction is antisymmetric because it's in the singlet state.

The Color wavefunction is symmetric for all mesons.

That leaves me with the flavor wavefunction - for the octet particles, the flavor seems anti-symmetric, and the total wave function is antisymmetric.

How is it possible ?

Comment: You might be in confusion about the symmetry of the total wavefunction w.r.t. interchanges with *other* particles (your red herring 2nd paragraph) versus interchanges of *constituents* within this wf. Further be advised the η' is a flavor singlet, unlike the iso-, U- and V- triplets, actually flavor symmetric, you are considering in isolation. Any book on the quark model should clarify all symmetry issues for you. Identical to the equally malformed [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318237/overall-symmetry-of-pion-wave-function).

Comment: O.k, I understand know the difference between changing particles or their constituents. From that counclusion, the total wave function must be anti-symmetric under exchange of two quarks because quarks are fermions. 
In the ground state, the spin wavefunction is anti-symmetric, the radial wavefunction of each quark is symmetric and the color is symmetric also. It means that the flavor wavefunction must be symmetric for exchange but it fits only the $\eta ' $ particle. Is something worng with this path of thinking?

Comment: Or maybe i'm wrong about the flavor wavefuctions. In the literature the flavor wavefunction is written as $|u\bar{d}>$ but maybe it's a linear combination of both orders?

Comment: Yes, you are confused about flavor. There is a minor sign wrinkle with antiquarks. Skip SU(3) and focus on isospin that you have spin experience with. The π+ so isotriplet you write is flavor symmetric. Lichtenberg, Kokkedee, etc... any book, not paper, on the subject should work.

Comment: This question [226493](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226493/quark-composition-of-the-neutral-pion) might help with pseudoreality, a sub-question that I feel coming...

Answer (score 0):

the parity for the spacial part is not what your wrote. It is actually  P=(−1)^L making it symmetrical. After that everything fits!